# Magento 2 Override minicart.phtml template?

Tags: magento2, overrides, mini-cart

This is the Magento core template path:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

I would like know how to override this template with my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple copy minicart.phtml from following

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

and put in

```
root/app/design/VenderName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

Flush your cache and check.

Comment: figure out the structure, Checkout is a Magento module it will be override like as theme override(Magento_Theme):
Core: `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\`
Override: `<vendor-name>\<theme-name>\Magento_Theme\`

So Checkout(Magento_Checkout):
Core: `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\`
Override: `<vendor-name>\<theme-name>\Magento_Checkout\`

minicart.phtml will be placed accordingly:
`<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`

So like this method any modules template can be override and customize.

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: I did the same for same file but it didnt worked. And debug mode displaying same file ie. /path-to-root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

and i cleard cache manually as well as with command: php bin/magento cache:flush though cache is already disabled.
-- whats wrong with it?

Comment: @jai : Did you tried after generating static contents??

Comment: Yes. [1] I created file [2] deployed [3] flushed cahce. I also tried same for list.phtml (/path/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml) but it also didnt work. really odd becasue i did following all guidelines. My magento version: 2.1.2

Comment: Its so simple but i dont know why its not working

Comment: I tried with another .phtml override. Here its: [1] Copy from /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link.phtml  to /app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name‌​>/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link.phtml (there is no other file in module-wishlist directory in my theme)[2] php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [3] php bin/magento cache:flush [4] Also manually deleted cache from PUB(except .htaccess) and VAR/view_preprocessed.... But in debug mode this .phtml file still diplaying from /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link.phtml.

Comment: I could not figure out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked was manually clearing the contents of `pub/static/` but make sure that you don't delete the .htaccess file inside pub/static/ folder

***Some of the things that I tried and didn't work***

1. Adding a mapping in requirejs-config.js (Both in the code and design folders)

   ```
   "map": {
       "*": {
           'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html': 'Magento_Theme/template/minicart/content.html'
       }
   }
   ```
2. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Vendor/module en_GB en_US`