# Override .phtml files in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, list.phtml

I have started working on Magento 2.1.2 and require to update few modules and files but I am not able to update .phtml files.

I have create theme with the name of theme and doing all by in theme folder:

1. vendor-name : Abc  (NameSpace)
2. theme-name‌​ : developer (theme_name)

ie: I tried with another .phtml override. Here its:

1. Copy from /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link‌​.phtml to /app/design/frontend/Abc/developer/module-wis‌​hlist/view/frontend/‌​templates/link.phtml (there is no other file in module-wishlist directory in my theme)
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. php bin/magento cache:flush
4. Also manually deleted cache from PUB(except .htaccess) and VAR/view_preprocessed

   But in debug mode this .phtml file still diplaying from /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link‌​.phtml

It may be duplicate for few question but i didnt get my answer by following below links:

1. [Override Magento 2 phtml Files?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/101501/29175)
2. [Magento 2 Override minicart.phtml template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/136311/29175) (My Comments are here)
3. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html
4. [How to override .phtml files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/116389/29175)
5. [Override PHTML files in Magento 2.1.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/139600/29175)

It should be very simple to override .phtml files, modules as well but I am not able to do this. It may be issue of Magento version 2.1.2? I apologies again if it's duplicate but I left with no option. I must be missing something very important.

Comment: You have to create first theme and after you can override file

Comment: I did same and qestion is also updated.

Comment: Please give me path of your theme

Comment: /app/design/frontend/Abc/developer and theme is working fine.

Comment: just to confirm you are checking same store ? where you activate your custom theme ?

Comment: Yes. I am working on same store from last week so there is no such confusion.

Comment: I dont know what was the problem. I backed up my custom work and reinstall magento. Followed the same guidelines and now its working. thanks for all who put there efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running from the cli

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Yes I did from CLI. but didnt work

Comment: before flushing the cache did you try a static-content:deploy?

Comment: or even try a **compile** command instead of deploy

Comment: I tried deploy only and flush after that

Answer (score 0):

You have to just below folder inside your theme,

Create **Magento_Wishlist** folder,

```
app/design/frontend/Abc/developer/Magento_Wishlist/‌​templates/link.phtml
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: i already did the same and cleared the cache manully and from CLI too.

Comment: Have you checked your wishlist module is enable?

Comment: yes, its enabled

Comment: May be you have to check for log file, above scenario is perfect for override any core file into module file.

Comment: May be you have used module-wis‌​hlist/view/frontend/‌​templates in your theme path you have to set only Magento_Wishlist/templates folder

Comment: Yes Sir, thats also tried. Should i deploy or compile before flush ? Or anything else

Comment: You can try with deploy command and remove var folder from root

Comment: This also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You have used like this,

Copy from

```
/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link‌​.phtml
```

to

```
/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{theme}/Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml
```

`Magento_Wishlist` instead of `module-wis‌​hlist`.

or

don't need to use `view/frontend` after `Magento_Wishlist`.

Comment: thats already tried

Comment: have you recompile after this?

Comment: Please check question under title "I tried with another .phtml override. Here its"  . Kindly let me know if more need to do there?

Comment: have you tried with `Magento_Wishlist` this folder?

Comment: yes its : /app/design/frontend/Abc/developer/module-wis‌​hlist/view/frontend/‌​templates/link.phtml

Comment: no, you have to use `/app/design/frontend/Abc/developer/Magento_Wishlist/templates/l‌​ink.phtml`. `Magento_Wishlist` instead of `module-wis‌​hlist`.

Comment: Used [1] - /app/design/frontend/Abc/developer/Magento_Wishlist/template‌​s/l‌​ink.phtml [2] php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [3] php bin/magento cache:flush . But still same problem